# My sql database rounds floats in php?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

**Code:**

```
if ($insert = $dbc->query("
    INSERT INTO Spotting_TB (s,p,lo,la,i,time_posted,hidden)
    VALUES (NULL,'{$p}','{$lo}','{$la}','{$i}',NOW(),'1')
    ")){}
```

**Result:**

138.675,
-34.8465

The number entered was like 138.67742, -34.8469685 for $lo and $la they are normal unique values in the database I am using php and the numbers some how got rounded but I want them to be precise.

Comment: what is data type of lo and la

Comment: I think its because of the column data type is integer. Change it to float

Comment: @DhavalBhavsar They are both floats in the db and on php, i casted them

Comment: @MayankPandey the column is a float

Comment: but in float how much ?

Comment: i think you use lo for float(7,3) and la (7,4)

Comment: **WARNING**: Using manual escaping is extremely error prone and a single mistake can lead to a crippling [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). Whenever possible use **prepared statements**. These are quite straightforward to do in [`mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) where any user-supplied data is specified with a `?` or `:name` indicator that’s later populated using `bind_param` or `execute` depending on which one you’re using.

Answer (score 1):

You should use your field type in the form  FLOAT(M,D).

(M,D) means than values can be stored with up to M digits in total, of which D digits may be after the decimal point.

Refer to this section: [Floating-Point Types](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/floating-point-types.html)

Changing your field type to **float(12,8)** should work just fine.